# Devise logs in, but doesn't seem to set session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I just upgraded to Devise 1.2 and now I can login, but then when I go to another page and the before_filter calls authenticate_account! (because my model is 'account', not 'user') it returns false, meaning I'm not logged it. It's as if the session cookie isn't getting created. What would cause this? I can't figure out how to track down what could be causing this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

or add before_filter :authenticate_user! in application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  protect_from_forgery 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create this for your before filter in your controllers:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Comment: this is actually what i'm doing, but i made a mistake in my initial question, but i just updated it.

Comment: why account_authenticated ? It should probably be "authenticate_account".

Comment: ok, i fixed this by upgrading devise, rails and jquery-rails. I think i had upgraded rails and a security fix in 3.0.4 broke it